# Can't install any composer in laravel 8 anymore

Tags: laravel

Whenever I try to install any composer using command `composer required composer_name` then it give me this error.

```
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

After searching solution I tried some. Mostly I found people getting resolve their problem by updating composer by using this command `composer update` or `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`.

But by running update commands I got this error

```
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

I searched but couldn't find any working solution. Any idea why I am unable to install any composer? I tried yajra and some other composer but failed.

> update

I got this error while running command `php artisan package:discover --ansi`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class env does not exist in D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:877
```

Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(877): ReflectionClass->__construct('env')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(758): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('env')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(841): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('env', Array, true)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(694): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('env', Array)
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('env', Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1423): Il in D:\xampp\htdocs\suo\webapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 879

Comment: Did you change `scripts.post-autoload-dump` section in composer.json?

Comment: @Maksim I never edit composer.json manually

Comment: try to run this command and check the error in console. `php artisan package:discover --ansi`

Comment: @Maksim  have updated question with your given command result

Comment: And just google it :) add TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true in your .env

Comment: I tried to took for it too but `<server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>` is already present in `phpunit.xml` in same folder where .env present

Comment: Is that all the stack trace there is? That's an exception from somewhere that is calling `app('env')` or something like that but the stack trace shared is only the last few calls happening within the container itself.

Comment: @apokryfos I got mentioned trace twice par command. Whenever i run either mentioned command or clear cache command I got trace twice i.e. dublicate. Once they print and then print same trace again.

Comment: I was asking if that is the entire trace (in both cases) or is that longer? Are other artisan commands working (e.g. `php artisan inspire`)

Comment: @apokryfos Your given command `php artisan inspire` isn't working either. Same response which I get with cache commands

Comment: That usually indicates that a service provider might be throwing that error. Try (1) delete any caches in `bootstrap/cache` and one by one comment out all the code in your own service providers until you find which one is not working and then take a look at any code that might be causing this issue

Comment: @apokryfos After digging for the solution for long, I found, when I install any composer then it deletes folder in `vendor/laravel`. And this cause error to come. I try to install same composer in newly setup laravel app, there it is not deleting folders. m not getting why this is happening

Comment: double-check your `composer.json` to make sure you've included `laravel/framework`  (or any specific `illuminate` package you may be using) and then try deleting your `composer.lock` file and running `composer install` again

Comment: @apokryfos I have the same issue with yajra datatables when I remove it from the composer command I got the same error and all solution dose not work with me, I cannot run PHP artisan, and for composer install when it finish it throw that error

Comment: @SWAT10101 I was able to resolve it by creating new laravel project and copy all view and model files, css and js to new project. And install all composer in new project setup which was installed in previous buggy project. And thats how it worked for me.